# Secure LDAP Alias Lookup through Sendmail

Tags: ssl, unix, ldap, solaris, sendmail

I'm trying to configure sendmail to use an LDAP lookup as an alias table.

I have this line in my config:

```
Kldapfullname ldap -k"uid=%s" -v"mail" -h"my-ldap-server"
```

I've been using that for a long time. It works, aliases get looked up, and email ends up in the proper inbox.

However, it's working because the LDAP is currently allowing anonymous binds. Due to some policy changes, this can't be done anymore.

I got this working:

```
Kldapfullname ldap -k"uid=%s" -v"mail" -H"ldaps://my-ldap-server/" -Msimple -d"CN=LDAP_USER" -P /path/to/ldap.secret
```

Which fulfills the requirement of "no more anonymous binds".

However there's still a bit of a security problem: The LDAP binding is not being done over a secure channel. The user name and password are both being sent in clear text. Which in the long run, is just as useful as leaving it to bind anonymously.

In several examples I saw while searching around, I saw that the `-H` flag lets you specify a protocol such as `ldap://`, or in my case `ldaps://`.

But when I went to verify, I saw that the data was still going through the non-secure LDAP port (Port 389) instead of the LDAPS port (Port 636). (I used `snoop` to see the traffic between my host and the LDAP server.)

So my questions are:
* Why is the `ldaps://` being ignored and being used as if it was just `ldap://`?
* What do I have to change in order to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the 4th edition of the "bat book" (section 3.4.56) when sendmail is compiled with LDAP support but without SM_CONF_LDAP_INITIALIZE the scheme:// part of the LDAP URL is omitted.